# Is this a virus?

Tags: windows-7, ntfs, virus, format

When I format My flash as `NTFS` right after the **Format Compeleted** window, I see that is has 1.83 GB free space.

[image]

But after 10 -20 second, the free space changes to 1.80 GB automatically!

[image]

I check contents of the flash memory By **CMD** , and there is no files there! neither hidden file nor system files!

```
C:\>dir H:\ /A
 Volume in drive H has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 5882-B4AA

 Directory of H:\

File Not Found

C:\>
```

**Q: Why?!**

Comment: Consider using [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to [check](http://blogs.technet.com/b/appv/archive/2008/01/24/process-monitor-hands-on-labs-and-examples.aspx) what's accessing the drive.

Comment: Try using a **Path begins with H:** filter.  Also, you might check if you get the same behavior if you [start Windows in Safe Mode](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/start-computer-safe-mode#start-computer-safe-mode=windows-7) or if you [perform a clean boot](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929135/en-us).

Answer (score 0):

Some types of malware can cause disk space loss, but typically the loss is much more significant than yours. For example a friend of mine lost 3.5 of his 4 GB flash drive. Try BootIce, it is supposed to restore lost space.

Comment: I don't want to restore it! I want to understand which data saved and which program doing it!